# session_unset($_SESSION)

Tags: php

Olá, a instrução `session_unset($_SESSION);` exclui todas as sessions existentes?

Eu tenho no servidor local wampserver aonde a variável de sessão fica no meu caso no seguinte caminho: `c:/wamp/tmp`, quando eu crio sessions nas minha paginas a pasta **tmp** recebe por exemplo uma session `$_SESSION['autentica'] = '1';` com o seguinte nome: `sess_qvin6nvoq52caubdumc8duq684` com os seguintes valores: **autentica|s:1:"1";** .

Quando eu uso `session_unset($_SESSION);` a instrução faz a exclusão de tudo o que esta nessa pasta (tmp).

a- Essa instrução vai *derrubar* outros usuários que estariam logados?

b- Existiria um meio de somente excluir a `sess_qvin6nvoq52caubdumc8duq684`, sem apagar as outras?

Pelo que pude ver nisso, acho que estou fazendo algo errado, porque ao criar as sessions, temos sempre algo sendo criado nessa pasta **tmp** do servidor php, mas percebi que acaba ficando arquivos que não são excluídos.

Penso que estou fazendo algo de errado na manipulação das sessions, pois sempre fica essa especie de *"sujeira"* na pasta **tmp** do servidor.

É possível evitar isso?

Answer (score 1):

Para que você mantenha a pasta **tmp** sem *"sujeira"*, a melhor opção é utilizar a **session_destroy** poís ela destroi todos os dados armazenados durante a sessão como pode ser visto [aqui](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.session-destroy.php)!

Já o **session_unset** que você está utilizando apenas limpa a variavel global **$_SESSION** como visto [aqui](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.session-unset.php).